# Eclipse Web Page Editor and AngularJS Editor missing

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How do I install **Web Page** and **AngularJS Editor**s to Eclipse (Kepler Service Release 2)?

※ Seen in for instance [this tutorial](http://blog.diniscruz.com/2014/02/using-angularjs-in-eclipse-part-1.html)

**Installed Software**

[image]

**Installed Plug-ins**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, it appears that the **AngularJS Editor** is not supported in Eclipse Kepler.

> AngularJS Eclipse is developed/tested with Eclipse 4.4 Luna. It is advised to use Eclipse 4.4 Luna (even if AngularJS Eclipse could work with older version of Eclipse).

Source: [angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse)

---

The **Web Page Editor** can be found in the *Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development* package.

Repository: Kepler - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler